# table-cell margin left and margin top not working

Tags: html, css

I try add margin top and margin left, but not working.

```
<li>li 1 <br/> new line</li>
<li>li 2 <br/> new line</li>
```

And CSS

```
li {
    list-style: none;
    counter-increment: foo;
    display: table-row;
}

li::before {
    content: "-";
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 5px;    
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/b5rtg568/

Comment: What do You want to achieve?

Comment: You can try getting a similar result using padding instead of margin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot apply margins on a `table-cell`, also the way you are trying to accomplish your task seems to be pretty weird, try using CSS positioning techniques for the same result and in a better way like

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/b5rtg568/1/)

[**Demo 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/b5rtg568/2/) *(Using `margin` on `li` elements)*

```
li {
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 15px;
    position: relative;
}

li::before {
    content: "-";
    position: absolute;
    left: -10px;
}
```

Here, am using CSS positioning techniques to move the `-` prefixes outside the list item by using negative value for `left` property. Here, you can now use `margin-top` and `margin-left` properties for your `li` elements, and if you need you can also position the `-` accordingly.

Some tips, instead of wrapping the text using `li` you should be using `p` tags or `<h2>` or `<h3>` tags which will give more semantic meaning to your content and you won't have to use dirty `<br>` tags to separate your content in two lines because that will be accomplished automatically if you will use the above elements I suggested which are *block level* by default and will take 100% of the space.

Answer (score 0):

Margin, padding, height will have no effect on 'table-row', hence you have to your li display property to 'block'.